# Modifying beamer's frame title template to change head/foot text colors for title page only

Tags: latex, beamer

Im building a beamer template for my university with a customized `frame title` template and I would like to have the `author`, `title` and `institute` fields displayed in the footline of all frames except in title page.

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338856/beamer-change-titlepage-not-to-show-details-in-headline-footline) discussion, I manage to do that by locally setting the footline font color equal to the footline background color in the title frame.

Even though this solution produces the output that I want, I would like to know if there is any way to obtain the same output by modifying the `frame title` template instead, so that all the customizations happen in the preamble.tex file.

### MWE:

#### main .tex file

```tex
\include{preamble}

\title{presentation-title}
\author{my-name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg} 
\frame{\titlepage}
}

\begin{frame}
    frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### preamble.tex file:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer} 

% Theme and sub theme 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usetheme{Berlin}                             
\usecolortheme{beaver}       

% Global color settings
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=Maroon}     
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=Maroon}  
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white, bg=Maroon}          

% Modified title page template
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

\insertauthor

\insertinstitute

\inserttitle

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this little trick to move your modifications to the preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

% Theme and sub theme 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usetheme{Berlin}                             
\usecolortheme{beaver}       

% Global color settings
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=Maroon}     
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=Maroon}  
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white, bg=Maroon}          

% Modified title page template
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

\insertauthor

\insertinstitute

\inserttitle

}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg} 
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother

\title{presentation-title}
\author{my-name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame}
    frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]